# Too good to be true raffle

Tags: real-estate, scams

There's a raffle here which seems too good to be true:

https://www.winapetloversdream.com.au/

It's a $59 entry fee for a $1m+ prize. I am particularly suspicious because there are no T&Cs published anywhere, and I have trouble seeing how the organiser benefits - they would have to sell more than 16,000 tickets to get the value of that property, which seems unlikely?

My friend went to uni with the person who runs that place (shown in the video) and thought she was an honest and lovely person.

Is this perhaps just a clever way of selling a property that she's having trouble selling?

Comment: Property raffles are increasingly popular: https://www.moneywise.co.uk/home-mortgage/buying/could-you-win-home-the-pros-and-cons-property-raffles

Comment: In many countries (e.g. UK) many of these "increasingly popular" raffles are actually illegal, because they do not comply with the fairness requirements of gambling legislation. In particular many "raffles" may actually be lotteries.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are T&C in the menu. They need minimum of 40,000 entries for the special prize....

> 11. It is a condition precedent of the major prize set out in clause 12 below being awarded that the Promoter receives a minimum of 40,000 entries into the promotion. In the event less than 40,000 entries are received, the major prize will not be awarded and the winner will receive the consolation prize as set out in clause 20.

Comment: Oh, I see. 40,000 * $60 = $2.4m, so they make a huge profit. If they don't reach that, they pay out 50% of the income as a consolation prize... so they still make a profit assuming the cost of fulfilment for the photos is less than $30. Clever. Not really a scam, though a bit misleading.